# UIButton changing position doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, position

I have a problem with changing the position of a UIButton, created in Interface Builder. I have an Outlet to it in one of my classes. Now I need to change the position of this button according to a User Default, saved in standard User defaults. The problem is, that the button's position won't change after calling this code:

`self.planButton.center = CGPointMake(244, 234);`

I have already tried to call `[self.planButton setNeedsDisplay]`

I have also tried to call `[self.view reloadInputViews]`with no effect.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you know the position of a button when you are making it hidden?

Comment: It's another button that is hidden...

Comment: @user666 simple option for you take x,y,width,height of that button from xib right menu and create it programatically then it will move easily.

Comment: Have you make Outlet perfectly? Can you get button object in planButton?

Comment: That would be perfectly fine, but isn't there any other solution involving Interface Builder? I have also tried to uncheck "Use AutoLayout" without effect...

Comment: OK I'm sorry, I have not made the IB Connection correctly. So this works now, but there is another problem: When this View Controller appears for the first time, the button's position is set correctly, but if I return to it again, the button's position is wrong...Anybody has an idea what could be the problem? I'm calling the method to reposition in `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setFrame`

```
[self.planButton setFrame:CGRectMake(244, 234, self.planButton.frame.size.width, self.planButton.frame.size.height)];
```

**EDIT:**

try this

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

If that doesn't work, You might want to do this in

`(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`  instead of `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work...the button keeps staying in the same position

Comment: Thanks! The `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method fixed it for me.